# Geometric Intuition Behind Metric Tensors?

Tags: differential-geometry, intuition, tensors, polar-coordinates

Given the metric tensor of a sphere in matrix form,
$$g_{ij}=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & r^2 & 0\\
0 & 0 & r^2\sin^2\theta
\end{bmatrix},\qquad x^i=(r,\theta,\phi)$$
I can't seem to understand why the $\textbf{e}_{\phi}$ basis vector given by $\sqrt{g_{\phi\phi}}=r\sin\theta$ is a function of $\theta$ in addition to $r$. If the manifold is spherically symmetric, why wouldn't $g_{\theta\theta}=g_{\phi\phi}$? Additionally, you could replace $r\sin\theta$ with $y$ in Cartesian coordinates, indicating that the magnitude of $\textbf{e}_{\phi}=0$ when $y=0$. I understand how the metric is derived but would appreciate some geometrical intuition.

Comment: It has to do with [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4377778/949989).

Comment: The coordinates $\theta$ and $\phi$ play different roles in the definition of spherical coordinates, so why would you expect $g_{\theta\theta} = g_{\phi\phi}$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [to prove $dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2 = dr^2 + r^2 d(\theta)^2 + r^2(\sin\theta)^2 d\phi^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3265077/to-prove-dx2-dy2-dz2-dr2-r2-d-theta2-r2-sin-theta2-d-phi)